# Does match sharing 952 cM indicate grandparent or great uncle?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis

My mother was adopted and we are trying to find the parents. I have a DNA match that is 952cM and 38 DNA segments.

What is the chance of this being my grandparent?

It says 1st cousin and we know through family it can't be that (age). Also falls in the great grandparent and we know that can't be the case. It says could be great uncle, which is slightly a possibility but the family doesn't think so. They think he is the grandfather.

Comment: It appears to be too low for a grandparent (according to [DNAPainter](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/952)

Answer (score 1):

From the [The Shared cM Project 3.0 tool v4 for 952 cM shared](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/952) the possibilities seem to be:

> 99.73%: Great-Grandparent Great-Aunt / Uncle Half Aunt / Uncle 1C Half Niece / Nephew Great-Niece / Nephew Great-Grandchild
>
> 0.27%: * Great-Great-Grandparent Great-Great-Aunt / Uncle Great-Great-Niece / Nephew Half Great-Aunt / Uncle Half Great-Niece /
>   Nephew 1C1R Half 1C

As you can see grandparent is not offered as a possibility  whereas great uncle is.